# The function deleting elements in jquery from html does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalSubscriptionForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
         aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header text-center">
                    <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Subscribe</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body mx-3">
                    <div class="md-form mb-5">
                        <i class="fas fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form3">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" id="form3" class="form-control validate val1" name="val1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-4">
                        <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form2">Desc</label>
                        <input type="email" id="form2" class="form-control validate val2" name="val2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form mb-4">
                        <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form2">
                            Coordinates click:
                            <div class="coorX"></div>
                            x
                            <div class="coorY"></div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-indigo saveBtn">Send <i class="fas fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scalize imgpo">
        <img src="img/jacket.png" alt="" class="target ">
        <div class="item-point" data-top="130" data-left="300" id="point1">
            <div><a href="#"  class="toggle tooltips" title="<h1><b>Another</b> <em>one</em> here too 1</h1>"  data-placement="top" data-html="true" rel="tooltip"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-point" data-top="180" data-left="462" id="point2">
            <div><a href="#" class="toggle tooltips" title="<h1><b>Another</b> <em>one</em> here too 2</h1>"  data-placement="top" data-html="true" rel="tooltip"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-point" data-top="380" data-left="215" id="point3">
            <div><a href="#"  class="toggle tooltips" title="<h1><b>Another</b> <em>one</em> here too 3</h1>"  data-placement="top" data-html="true" rel="tooltip"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-point"  data-left="357"  data-top="458" id="point4">
            <div><a href="#"  class="toggle tooltips" title="<h1><b>xxxxx</b> <em>one</em> here too 4</h1>"  data-placement="top" data-html="true" rel="tooltip"></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-rounded mb-4 formAdd" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalSubscriptionForm" style="display:none"></a>

<form name="saveForm" action="#" method="post" style="margin-left: 15px">
    <div class="itemsBox" >
        <div class="obiect1">Obiect 1 <div class="removeMe" id="1">X</div> </div>
        <div class="obiect2">Obiect 2 <div class="removeMe" id="2">X</div> </div>
        <div class="obiect3">Obiect 3 <div class="removeMe" id="3">X</div> </div>
        <div class="obiect4">Obiect 4 <div class="removeMe" id="4">X</div> </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.imgpo').click(function(e) {
            var posX = $(this).position().left,posY = $(this).position().top;
            $('.coorX').html((e.pageX - posX -10));
            $('.coorY').html((e.pageY - posY -10));
            $(".tooltip").tooltip("hide");
            $('.formAdd').click();
        });



          $(document).on("click", ".removeMe", function() {
            var number = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#point' + number).remove();
            $('.obiect' + number).remove();
        });



        $('.saveBtn').click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var val1 = $(".val1").val(); // title
            var val2 = $(".val2").val(); // description
            var cX = $(".coorX").text();
            var cY = $(".coorY").text();

            var newPoint = "<div class='item-point' data-top='"+cY+"' data-left='"+cX+"' id='point1'>" +
                               "<div>" +
                                  "<a href='#'  class='toggle tooltips' title='<h1><b>"+val1+"</b><br>"+val2+"</h1>'  data-placement='top' data-html='true' rel='tooltip'></a>" +
                               "</div>" +
                            "</div>";

            var nextObjNumber = $(".itemsBox").children("div").length + 1;

            var newObject = "<div class='obiect" + nextObjNumber + "'>Obiect " + nextObjNumber + 
                                "<div class='removeMe' id='"+nextObjNumber+"'>X</div>" + 
                            "</div>";

            $(".scalize").append(newPoint); // inserting new point
            $(".itemsBox").append(newObject); // inserting new object


            $('.scalize').scalize({
                styleSelector: 'circle',
                animationPopoverIn: 'flipInY',
                animationPopoverOut: 'flipOutY',
                animationSelector: 'pulse2'
            });



            const $tooltip = $('.tooltips');

            $tooltip.tooltip({
                html: true,
                trigger: 'click',
                placement: 'top',
            });

            $tooltip.on('show.bs.tooltip', () => {
                $('.tooltip').not(this).remove();
            });

            $tooltip.on('click', (ev) => { ev.stopPropagation(); });


            $("#modalSubscriptionForm").modal("hide");

            $(".val1").val("");
            $(".val2").val("");

            alert('Add!');

        });


        $('.scalize').scalize({
            styleSelector: 'circle',
            animationPopoverIn: 'flipInY',
            animationPopoverOut: 'flipOutY',
            animationSelector: 'pulse2'
        });


        const $tooltip = $('.tooltips');

        $tooltip.tooltip({
            html: true,
            trigger: 'click',
            placement: 'top',
        });

        $tooltip.on('show.bs.tooltip', () => {
            $('.tooltip').not(this).remove();
        });

        $tooltip.on('click', (ev) => { ev.stopPropagation(); });


    });
</script>
```

I have a problem with deleting some elements. After clicking anywhere on the jacket's photo, a form will pop up adding a new point in the picture (where you click). Under the photo I have a list of point names from "X" which causes deleting points from the image. This works fine, but only for elements added at page startup (when the website is refreshed).

I have a problem with the newly added points in the image. They are deleting from the list below the picture. Points do not delete from the picture.

How to fix it?

Prview: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/pub/component/index2.html

Comment: `data-left='"+cX+"' id='point1'>"`  Your new point is being given a static `point1` id.  That id already exists on the page, so it's a duplicate, and invalid.  It also will not match your dynamic `nextObjNumber` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're creating your new point, you have `var newPoint = "<div class='item-point' data-top='" + cY + "' data-left='" + cX + "' id='point1'>" +`. The `id` is being set to 'point1' for every new point added. If you update that to set the `id` dynamically to match the `id` of the remove button that you're creating, it should work as expected.